# jQuery.ajax on onbeforeunload event not working

Tags: php, jquery

I have one php page like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload  = saveBeforeExit;
function saveBeforeExit() {  
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"truncate_logs.php",
        type:"GET",
        async:false,
        success:function(data){

        }
    })
}
</script>

//I am creating 'logs_".$t.".xls' here

<?php
header("Location: log_files/logs_".$t.".xls");
?>
```

My problem is here on

**Location:onbeforeunload is not getting called.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onbeforeunload  is not working because it isn't coded properly. You need to return a string from onbeforeunload , which will be used as the message in the window that will appear.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer. Add async : false to your jquery ajax request.

See [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-req)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it with :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = '';
    }

    // For Chrome and Safari
    return '';
};
```

However Opera does not seem to catch onbeforeunload event, so bad !

Answer (score 2):

Your assign to the event probably comes too early (page not ready).
Please try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onbeforeunload  = saveBeforeExit;
});
```